# How to cut and paste or move each footnote content next to footnote mark in ms-word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA. I need help. How to cut and paste (or move) the each footnote content next to the respective footnote indicator in Body Text. While placing the text, i need to place in between XML Tag `<Footnote>..</Footnote>`. For example Footnote indicator `1` was replaced with `<Footnote>Respective footnote content</Footnote>`

My Input DOC file

[image]

My needed Output file

[image]

When i was refer at [online](https://word.tips.net/T000313_Moving_Footnote_Text_into_the_Document.html#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20use%20the,then%20deletes%20the%20footnote%20reference) there was a macro which was selecting each footnote indicator manually for placing in the body text. My Document have more footnote text, it was difficult to use this macro each time for all footnotes.

Please help me in this regarding for creating the VBA Scripts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @braX - Actually i new to VBA. I am referring the [website1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/converting-footnote-numbers-and-text-to-plain-text/a97dff42-0346-48ba-a0c9-60800a15e775?tab=AllReplies#tabs)  [website2](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/34254-how-change-superscript-footnotes-into-genuine-word.html) for testing. But i get no ideals from these websites.

Comment: People here will help you with code you are using, they will not write an application for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub MoveFootNotes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngSrc As Range, RngTgt As Range, f As Long
With ActiveDocument
  For f = .Footnotes.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Footnotes(f)
      Set RngSrc = .Range
      Set RngTgt = .Reference
      With RngTgt
        .Collapse wdCollapseStart
        .FormattedText = RngSrc.FormattedText
        .InsertBefore "<Footnote>"
        .Characters.Last.Next.InsertBefore "</Footnote>"
      End With
      .Delete
    End With
  Next
End With
Set RngSrc = Nothing: Set RngTgt = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering again. While using your macro Last character was deleted. The output was `<Footnote>Woodger, M. Private Communication</Footnote>`, here End Period (.) was missing after the macro was Run. My colleague was manually adding Space at end of each footnote (now only came to know). Please suggest any solution here